# Failed to get access to local media on android webview

Tags: android, webview, webrtc

I am trying to make a webview that contains a webRTC, but when I try to give join to access a room, I get the following error: ***"Failed to get access to local media. Error name was NotAllowedError. Countinuing without sendig to stream"***. Thanks in advance.

[Here is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UYGCw.jpg)

```
@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnable")
private void initWebView(){
    webView = findViewById(R.id.WebViewID);
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){

        @Nullable
        @Override
        public Bitmap getDefaultVideoPoster() {
            return Bitmap.createBitmap(10, 10, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        }
    });

    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webSettings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
    webSettings.setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);
    webView.loadUrl(url);
}


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"/>
```

Comment: Post the code for others to refer, without the code this is difficult to understand.

Comment: There is what i did.

Answer (score 0):

It is not enough to declare permissions in the manifest by:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"/>
```

You will have to either ask for these permissions to be granted by the user in code ([reference](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting)) or go manually to permissions settings in the device and grant the desired application `Camera` and `Microphone` permissions. Doing so should resolve the issue.